# How can get access to Unity container in a class library ActionFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, class-library, actionfilterattribute

So, I have a web project that utilizes Unity to inject `UserRepository` for interfaces `IUserRepository`.  I have a class library which contains a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`.  This custom attribute class is used on many actions already.  I want to add some code to it to check for a value in the database based on a user.  To do this, I need access to the `UserRepository`.  I could do it the old fashioned way with using statements and directly access `UserRepository`, but I would like to utilize the DI and resolve `IUserRepository`.  How can I get access to what the web is resolving `IUserRepository` to, inside the custom attribute class since `ActionFilterAttribute` needs an empty constructor?

Comment: One approach - https://eagle081183.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/dependency-injection-with-asp-net-mvc-action-filters/ . Side note: I believe what you trying to do is bad idea because you injecting synchronous remote calls into request -  personal preference.

Comment: Prefer a life [without dependency injection in attributes](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  I agree.  After talking with some people, we decided there was a better place to do my check.  I am still going to post an answer as the solution can be used elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, although I decided to not do the user check inside the custom attribute, the solution to allow for the injection inside the custom attribute can be used elsewhere.  I had a property in the attribute:

```
public IUserRepository UserRepository { get; set; }
```

In the web's Global.asax.cs, I injected it via a property injection:

```
container.RegisterType<NameOfCustomAttribute>(new InjectionProperty("UserRepository", 
                                        new UserRepository(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBName"].ConnectionString)));
```

Comment: There is some piece of magic that you are missing from your answer - normally attribute creation does not go through DI container at all.

Comment: Hmm, this is a pretty big application that I am delving into.  I will see if there is something that I am missing.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  As I am new the Unity and my current project, I searched the web to see if you were correct.  All of the examples that I found showed to do it the way I did.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx, http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2014/01/23/introduction-to-dependency-injection-with-unity.aspx, http://tmont.com/blargh/2010/12/non-magic-property-injection-in-unity

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are metadata objects. They shouldn't be involved in database access. Use a separate service to read the attribute values and as a result access the database.

Comment: Although your suggestion is a "better" design, it does not actually answer my question.  In my opinion, this should be a comment to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I found you can access your dependency resolution in an `ActionFilterAttribute` by using the `actionContext` parameter like so:

```
MyFooService myFooService = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(MyFooService)) as MyFooService;
```